# Unique but the latest rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max, greatest-n-per-group

I am using mysql 5.7 server and I have the following table with `id` as PRIMARY KEY.

## My Table

```sql
mysql> select * from abc;
+----+---------+-------+
| id | name    | place |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 | asd1    | abcd1 |
|  2 | asd2    | abcd1 |
|  3 | asd1    | abcd2 |
|  4 | asd3    | abcd1 |
|  5 | asd4    | abcd1 |
|  6 | asd1    | abcd1 |
|  7 | asd2    | abcd2 |
|  8 | asd3    | abcd2 |
|  9 | asd4    | abcd2 |
| 10 | asd3    | abcd1 |
| 11 | asd4    | abcd1 |
| 12 | asd4    | abcd2 |
| 13 | asd1    | abcd2 |
+----+---------+-------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## Expected Result

I want to select the rows with unique `name` having the latest `id`.

I other words, my expected result should be as following:

```sql
+----+---------+-------+
| id | name    | place |
+----+---------+-------+
| 13 | asd1    | abcd2 |
|  7 | asd2    | abcd2 |
| 10 | asd3    | abcd1 |
| 12 | asd4    | abcd2 |
+----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## What I tried

```sql
mysql> select * from abc group by name order by id desc;
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | place |
+----+------+-------+
|  5 | asd4 | abcd1 |
|  4 | asd3 | abcd1 |
|  2 | asd2 | abcd1 |
|  1 | asd1 | abcd1 |
+----+------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from (select * from abc as t order by t.id desc) as st1 group by t1.orderID;
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | place |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | asd1 | abcd1 |
|  2 | asd2 | abcd1 |
|  4 | asd3 | abcd1 |
|  5 | asd4 | abcd1 |
+----+------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from abc l inner join (select * from abc group by name) r on l.id = r.id;
+----+------+-------+----+------+-------+
| id | name | place | id | name | place |
+----+------+-------+----+------+-------+
|  1 | asd1 | abcd1 |  1 | asd1 | abcd1 |
|  2 | asd2 | abcd1 |  2 | asd2 | abcd1 |
|  4 | asd3 | abcd1 |  4 | asd3 | abcd1 |
|  5 | asd4 | abcd1 |  5 | asd4 | abcd1 |
+----+------+-------+----+------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

## Question

What will be the correct SQL to get the **Expected result**? Precise and simple one will be preferred.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: But note that this is the most frequently asked question under this tag

Comment: @Strawberry I also asked for a solution. I just want precise and simple one if possible. but my priority is for a solution.

Comment: Please share the expected result and the attempts you've tried so far

Comment: Yes, I have added the expected output. Hope this will help.

Comment: You didn't provide an attempt, so this question really reads like a do-the-work-for-me question, because you can't be bothered to learn SQL or read through related articles that show how to use `GROUP BY`. Question down-voted because it "does not show any research effort" *(quote from tooltip of down-vote button)*.

Comment: @Andreas I think I have added some attempts that I tried previously. I should add them previously. But I was in a hurry to get the answer. That is why maybe I did not add them at that time. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Down-vote removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the top record per group with a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*
from abc a
where a.id = (select max(a1.id) from abc a1 where a1.name = a.name)
order by a.name
```

For performance with this query, you want an index on `(name, id)`.

Comment: the answer gives me what I need right now, but I did not get what do want to mean by the suggestion for performance issue. Can u describe me?

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma: I mean that if you increase the performance of this query, you can create an index on columns `(name, id)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM abc t1
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT MAX(id) id, name
               FROM abс
               GROUP BY name ) t2
```

[fiddle with NATURAL JOIN](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0813c4f7a90e5eb94109d9ceb5410522)

[fiddle with JOIN .. USING](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a91781b745306a88b1e451c2df0a444c)

[fiddle with JOIN .. ON](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b7a390d8a29c5a1ae03ac291a0fc740f)

[fiddle with cartesian and WHERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=362eb0ca9fb0acade64bfca6d036ce03)

Comment: this does not give what I need?

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma Prove your words. PS. Fiddle added.

Comment: But your query fails in my local setup. Btw, when I change your query to `SELECT t1.*
FROM abc t1
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(id) id, name
               FROM abс
               GROUP BY name ) t2 using (id, name)`, only then it gives me the result.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma *But your query fails in my local setup.* That is transferring problem, not query problem. Test: simply re-type the query "by hands" (not copy-paste)... PS. If the amount of distinct `name` values is high the performance of the solution provided by GMP may be bettter.

Comment: Your provided query and the fiddle query are not the same. If you look closely you can find it. In the answer you have provided `natural join` but not in the fiddle link. Moreover there is no `using (id, name)` part in the answer but is in the fiddle link. On top of that I need to say that I am using docker container for this purpose. So you can not just say it as `transferring problem, not query problem`.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma Answer updated, all 4 forms of a query added. *So you can not just say it as transferring problem, not query problem.* All 4 variants works correctly giving the same result. So I **CAN**. All these 4 forms are aliases of the same query algo.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. And now I am removing my downvote and giving a +1 :).

Answer (score -1):

Do you need below -

```
SELECT MAX(id), name
FROM abc
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: @Ankit this does not give the latest place. I asked for latest unique rows

Comment: @Gosfly You can see the expected result I added to the que.